# How to make a webscraper that would work in a HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm having trouble with trying to make a webscraper that would work on a website. I'm very new to JavaScript and HTML and I have been trying to make a website sort of thing that counts how many people have a certain steam username but I couldn't find any Steam API that could do that. At first I used Node but since that doesn't work on HTML I tried to use browserify to import the modules that I used, cheerio and request, but that doesn't seem to work for what I'm doing. I'm trying to make it so that when I press the button it will get some info from a website (I just used a random wikipedia article to test) and write it on the website.

This is the main.js:

```
function getData(){
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Hemingway'
}, (err, res, body) => {

    if (err) return console.error(err);

    let $ = cheerio.load(body);

    let title = $('title');

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title.text();
});
}
```

This is the HTML (it's pretty basic):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<h1>Test</h1>

<input type="button" onclick="getData()" value="Display">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

I've already bundled the modules using browserify but it still won't work. Also I'm using VS Code. Please tell me if I've done something wrong thank you!

Comment: Define "won't work".

Comment: @SuperStormer When I try pressing the button it doesn't write the what it should've scraped, nothing happens. Even if I try just making it write a test thing like making it say "done at the end".

Comment: [Greetings, Fellow Human](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/hearthstone_gamepedia/images/4/45/Convincing_Infiltrator_full.jpg). Have you tried adding a console.log call to make sure the getData function is actually being run? How about defining the head and/or body and moving the "script src" lines outside the body?

Comment: @l3l_aze sorry I didn't get back to you, this is very helpful but I was able to get it working before that and forgot about this question! I'll put up the answer soon!

Comment: No problem, just trying to help where I can. Had a lot of problems with similar things myself, and these have become two early debugging steps. Often I would just make the JS inline from the start to avoid this.